# Manipulate incoming HTML data

Tags: safari, security, internet, web-browsing

[My ISP](http://telkomspeedy.com/), injects JavaScript code into every website I visit. Is there a way to filter all incoming traffic in OS X and remove that injected code?

Comment: There is [greasekit](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20718/greasekit) with which you can inject your user scripts (you must design yours) which will remove the unwanted scripts. If you can provide more info about the javascript which is injected, I can try to write a javascript to solve this problem.

Comment: Which URL is the javascript?

Comment: Use a VPN, better and safer solution than an userscript (the ISP's JS may execute before your userscript removes it so it's pointless).

Comment: Also, @Till, I recommend retitling this question to something like “Manipulate incoming HTTP responses”, since that will also cover anything else your ISP may try to shove on you.  (And I laud your efforts to break free of their crappy behavior!)

Answer (score 1):

That will be incredibly hard. It would be far easier to establish a VPN connection to get out from under the offending hostile network.

If you can ensure SSL connections and the network isn’t a very strong state actor, you might get pretty good immunization / isolation from that sort of tampering.

Barring that, keep the OS updates as far as possible as Apple continues to enhance security and privacy and this sort of attack leaves you extremely vulnerable to snooping, security risks and data leakage from the sites you enter data.